# Spring MVC jsp view

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

To design views that each jsp views have common navigation menu ( a treetable, when clicking on a tree node it navigates to another page) what is a good approach for this?

Adding a new node to navigation menu will effect all pages.
Navigation menu tree nodes will be populated from db (a menu table on db)
Is it possible to cache menu view on client so navigation menu will not be populated each time user navigates another page?

Thank you

Comment: Sitemesh is the way to go

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439651/sitemesh-or-tiles : Seems sitemesh doesn't have active development going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two separate questions asked in the post, I will answer them accordingly:

**1)** I would recommend using a Template Engine which integrates with JSPs.

[Apache Tile](https://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/basic/pages.html)s fits in this category. Using this framework, you can define template which contains common sections for header, footer, body and menu layouts. Furthermore, it supports derived templates via inheritance.

**2)** Caching solution : Since you want to load values from database to make the menu dynamic, caching and pre-populating the menu will minimize page load times. ***This should be done on server side.***

A separate thread/process should be made responsible for pre-populating and refreshing cache periodically.

From clean code perspective, JSP or Tiles template should not invoke database calls. Instead the page should interact with a DAO/component to separate concerns and ensure MVC pattern is not broken.

Helpful links:
Tiles [Example](http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/spring-mvc-and-apache-tiles-integration-example/)
[Thymeleaf](https://spring.io/blog/2012/10/30/spring-mvc-from-jsp-and-tiles-to-thymeleaf) - an alternative to Tiles